# Kotlin: Unit Test getView method of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing, mockito-kotlin

I have the following simple `ArrayAdapter` that I'd like to run UnitTests on:

```
class AccountSpinnerAdapter(context: Context, textViewResourceId: Int, private val values: Set<Account>) : ArrayAdapter<Account>(context, textViewResourceId, values.toList()) {

    override fun getCount() = values.size
    override fun getItem(position: Int) = values.elementAt(position)
    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val label = super.getView(position, convertView, parent) as TextView
        label.text = values.elementAt(position).displayName
        return label
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val label = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent) as TextView
        label.text = values.elementAt(position).displayName
        return label
    }
}
```

`getCount`, `getItem` and `getItemId` is easily done.

But **how can I test the `getView` and `getDropDownView` methods?** Problems that I am facing are:

- the 3rd parameter `viewGroup` can not be `null`. How to fake/mock this `ViewGroup`?
- both methods are calling `super.xxx`. How can I set up a `when/then` construct to let it return a `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't test any android dependency on JVM, because you don't have context to be able to get views or anything related to it, to test `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` you have 2 options

1. Write Instrumentation test using espresso or equivalent (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests)
2. Write your tests to run on JVM using Android shadows by using Robolectric, http://robolectric.org

Answer (score 0):

For *unit tests* the whole view should be mocked with `view = mock()` on `@Before` the test.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nhaarman/mockito-kotlin
testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.6.0'
```

see: [Android Unit Testing with Mockito](https://www.raywenderlich.com/195-android-unit-testing-with-mockito).